# Is there is any iOS App which uses icon fonts for iOS Designs?

Tags: ios, xcode, icon-fonts

I have not even found a single article where they are talking about **icon fonts for iOS Development**. Is there is any reason for not using icon fonts in iOS Development?

Instead they prefer to use icons in pdf format.

Answer (score 0):

Icon fonts are fine in iOS. You can mix images and different text fonts within an **NSAttributedString** and you can adjust the baseline for each so that you can deal with any vertical alignment issues. 
Icons as images opens up the opportunity to alter tintColor and play with animations in a simple way, as well as producing multi-color icons that would not be possible with a simple font.

Comment: Do you know any iOS app which uses font icons?

Comment: I've used some in the past but iOS sometimes has problems with "invalid" fonts... or fonts that it sees as invalid. These tend to misread the heights and vertical spacing.